# What all can I specify to params argument while creating a lgbm dataset or in the lgbm train API?

Tags: lightgbm

[lgbm datasets](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.Dataset.html) take a `params` argument. The document only says

> params (dict or None, optional (default=None)) – Other parameters for Dataset.

Similarly for [lgbm train](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.train.html), it also takes a `params` argument

> params (dict) – Parameters for training. Values passed through params take precedence over those supplied via arguments.

What can be specified in each? I am unable to find a resource detailing the same. I am looking for an exhaustive list of keys for each `params` dictionary

Answer (score 0):

The complete list of available parameters that can be passed via `params` in `lightgbm` (the LightGBM Python library) is documented at https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.5/Parameters.html.

You can use the drop-down menu there to switch to versions of that documentation corresponding to different releases of the library, and to `latest` for documentation corresponding to the current development version of the project from https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM.